# Redirect (htaccess) example.com/myproject to another subfolder but keep original url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

maybe someone can help. I try to redirect:

**www.example.com/myproject**

to

**www.example.com/projects/myproject**

but i want that the original url keeping.

**My current file tree:**

"/" webspace root

"/sites" this directory will called by typing www.example.com

"/sites/projects/myproject" in this folder i want to redirect the user if they type in the url field "www.example.com/myproject"

**What i have tried**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com/myproject$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/projects/myproject%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If i call "http://example.com/projects/myproject" it will work. But not "http://example.com/myproject".

Paramters should also work with original URL like "?site=register" or something like that.

---

**EDIT**

I have found now a solution myself:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^myproject/?$ /projects/myproject/%1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works fine and keeps the original URL.

One thing. Is it possible to to match file calls? Means:

Working URL: example.com/projects/myproject/css/main.css
Wanted URL with the above RewriteCondition: example.com/myproject/css/main.css

Currently it only shows me index.php but in the URL stays also "/myproject/css/main.css". I want to call this file. Same for js,pdf,less and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` only contains the hostname, not the `REQUEST_URI`, so you can't test for the presence of `myproject` in there.

I guess something like this would suffice:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^myproject/(.+) /projects/myproject/%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey. Its not working :-/ Just throw a 404. Ich changed the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^myproject/?$ /projects/myproject [R=301,L,QSA]`  and now it works but not with keeping the original URL. Can you help?

Comment: I found now a solution by myself. Can you check edited question?

Comment: I edited my answer, it had indeed a typo :-) Basically, you need to use brackets on the left side of the rewrite rule to specify what `%1` is referring to.

Comment: You didn't provide any input on the answer I provided. Gently reminding you to give some feedback / vote / accept if that helped :-)